# jQuery mask percent for any value

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask, percentage

I want to get a mask for a percentage value in JavaScript from **00,00** to **99,99**.

This mask need to accept any value, this is the values that can accept for example

> 1  11  11,1  11,11

This is my code:
HTML:

```
<input id="per" type="text"></input>
```

and JS:

```
$("#per").mask("9?9,99");
```

But when I try insert `11` this change to `11,`. How i remove the `,` in this cases?

Here is my mask: http://jsfiddle.net/SEXAj/2763/

Comment: please, can you add your code here? The jsfiddle is ok but you should post your code here!

Comment: there are nothing else, only this

Comment: `$('#per').val().replace(/,$/,'')` by using regular expression and replace ending comma with empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This different mask plugin https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ does exactly what you want. You can try it, follow the link

Comment: I can't change the plugin

Answer (score 2):

You can use this with blur event:

```
$("#per").mask("9?9,99").blur(function(){
  var rg = /\,+\d/g; // regular expression for comma and number
  if(!rg.test(this.value)){ // check if value doesn't have any num after comma
    this.value = this.value.split(',')[0]; // then just split the value and
  }                                        // assign the index[0]
});
```

[Updated Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/SEXAj/2767/)

Comment: I try this, but the output of $("#per").val() keeps "11,"

Comment: @gFontaniva did you checked the fiddle? Do one thing check console for any error.